# When I run rake db:seed, I keep getting "rake aborted! ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to! "

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run our company product source code on a local host. I have tried placing

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost:3000" }
```

in all development.rb, test.rb and production.rb.
But when I run

```
rake db:seed
```

I still keep getting

```
ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true.
```

I am adding my config/database.yml file as suggested in the edit
config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ******
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: company_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: coompany_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: company_production
  username: company
  password: <%= ****** %>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Please edit your question posting your `config/database.yml` file. Be careful and mask all possible passwords this file may contain before posting.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida I have added database.yml. Please check

Comment: Try adding a line with `host:     localhost` right after `default: &default` in your `config/database.yml` and then run the command again, please.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida  I added   `host: localhost` under `default: &default` 
still getting the same exact error.

Comment: does rake also fail when you try other rake tasks? for example "rake db:migrate" ?

Comment: @saadlulu `rake db:create` gives `developmet already exists` `test already exists` and `rake db:migrate` didnt give any errors it created all the migrations.

Comment: @user3576036 can you for the sake of debugging this, remove all data from your seed and run "rake db:seed" and tell us what happens

Comment: @saadlulu I removed all the data on **seeds.rb** and ran `rake db:seed` no error and didn't populate any data. And I tried your answer `rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=development`. Still same error.

Comment: @user3576036 your seed data file might be corrupted, try a single entry now and check. you may also be trying to insert duplicate data, or you are inserting into the wrong database, try my answer below

Comment: @saadlulu as you mentioned I started seeding the instructions from **seeds.rb** one by by one. It started creating. The issue is with this instruction `puts "\n######################## Creating Super Admin ########################\n"
AdminUser.create!(email: 'super_admin@example.com', name: 'Super Admin', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password', role: 'super_admin', active: true)`. Do you know what might be the issue with this line?

Comment: @user3576036 way to find out whats the problem with this is to go to your console and create a new object with that data `user = AdminUser.new(email: 'super_admin@example.com', name: 'Super Admin', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password', role: 'super_admin', active: true)` .. then you can call `user.valid?` and `user.errors.all`

Comment: @saadlulu I ran `user = AdminUser.new(email: 'super_admin@example.com', name: 'Super Admin', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password', role: 'super_admin', active: true)` on rails console. And `user.valid?` gave `=> true `.

Comment: @user3576036 try to save that object, Im suspecting that you already have that record and your primary key/validation is firing up. check and let us know whats the result please. oh and double check that your seed and console are working on the same environment.

Comment: @saadlulu I ran `user.save` and it gave     '  AdminUser Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `admin_users` WHERE `admin_users`.`email` = BINARY 'super_admin@example.com' LIMIT 1
`  `UserMailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 320.4ms
` and again followed that template error `ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
`

Comment: @saadlulu After I ran the above coomand and it said "AdminUser Exists"  I checked on console running `AdminUser.all` it returned no records at all and no super_admin object

Comment: @user3576036 well you have many options to decide from now, either find the user thats causing the problem and remove it, remove all users if all the users are fake, connect to another empty database if all the data is in the seed and you dont have any real data. go nuts and best of luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I forgot to answer it sorry. The solution might vary for this particular error for everyone. But for me I had to do the following changes in the following files.

In application.yml I added

```
SMTP_HOST: 'localhost:3000'
```

And in development.rb I added

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

Seeding done.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to populate the development environment with seed, if that was the case then try this

```
rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=development
```